# Python script runs flawless when executed in shell, but throws unicode errors when executed as systemd service

Tags: python, unicode, systemd

I have a python program that runs flawlessly in a `screen`. Now I wanted to switch from using a screen to run the script in to a `systemd` service. The program is a telegram-bot that often enough sends text that include umlauts like `Schweineschnitzel "Toscana" mit würziger Kräuterpanade`, but it worked flawless when executed as shell script, even when printing the texts to the terminal.

I did not make any changes to the code itself, I just put the file as the `ExecStart` in a .service-File, and expected the program to work just normally.

But instead, I get this output from `systemctl status` as error when trying to print my texts:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 132: ordinal not in range
```

Is there anything diffrent environment-wise in a systemd-Service that I have to configure so that for some reason in one case non-ascii-symbols can be handled in one case properly and in the other not?

Comment: try setting your default encoding to UTF-8 instead of ASCII

Comment: You progam needs to run in a process that has a UTf-8 `locale`, or you should set the PYTHIOENCODING environment variable tu UTF8.

Comment: It is called `PYTHONIOENCODING`, proof:  https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING

Answer (score 1):

Set PYTHONIOENCODING in your *.service file. Example of a file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Admin App
Requires=wallet.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/wallet/wallet/src
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/home/wallet/wallet"
Environment="PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1"
Environment="PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF8"
Environment="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings.prod"
ExecStart=gunicorn src.wsgi
```

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING